# White colors in view port vs render output Eevee

Tags: rendering, texturing, shaders, eevee-render-engine

[image]

Hi all, I'm hoping someone could help me with this problem here, which I believe is a shader's problem?
Left side is the render output, the right side is the viewport rendered view, eevee.
The viewport is what I want. The chairs, tablestops and cloth in the background show a nice white, and in the settings, all color settings are set to max white. So when in the render output they turn out this dark grey......I'm dumbfounded. The light source of this scene is from emissive material from the squares on the ceiling, so they look white. What's a tip that would make the emissive white more emissive and the greys more white?

Thank you.

Comment: Eevee is not a raytracing engine and so the meshes with emissive materials don't cast any light into the scene.

Comment: I see! So I'd have to either do this in cycles or replace all the emissive squares with area lights?

Comment: Yes, Cycles. Or in Eevee maybe take one area light that spans across all the emissive panels.

Answer (score 1):

To make emission lighting work properly in EEVEE, you need to use an Irradiance Volume (under "Light Probes" in add menu).

[image: Irradiance1]

As you can see, without the volume, as soon as the emission object is out of camera view, the light from it disappears:

[image: IrradianceBlank]

Scale the volume to encompass the area you want to boost the accuracy of the lighting (including emission values). You can adjust the detail from the properties panel.

[image: Irradiance2]

Additionally, you need to bake the indirect lighting. Otherwise, although emission materials may glow (with bloom), they do not provide any lighting

[image: Irradiance3]

Although I realize now I had some world lighting adding to the situation in the first image, you can still see that the lighting is more pronounced in this last photo. Also notice the lack of any light in my scene tree. All lighting is through emissions (except for a small amount of world lighting - that is a failure of my example, but does not change the effectiveness of the Irradiance Volume)

[image: Irradiance4]

You can see the difference, as the room is now lit, even though the emission object is out of camera view:

[image: Irrglow]

Comment: Cool! Thanks! I'll try this as well. the thing is that I do have both irradiance volume and reflectance cube set up, but not to the resolution you suggest, i'll try increasing the resolution.